# Rotating a matrix to become symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Given an $n \times n$ matrix Q having eigenvalues in $(0,1],$ is it possible to find an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix $U$ such that $$(QU)^T = QU$$ holds and the eigenvalues of $QU$ also fall in $(0,1]$? If so, is the orthogonal matrix unique?

Comment: What work have you done? What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you found is the [Polar Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition#Matrix_polar_decomposition). Any square matrix $Q$ can be written as $Q=UM$, where $U$ is unitary (orthogonal if $Q$ is real) and $M$ is positive-definite and symmetric (actually, $M=(Q^*Q)^{1/2}$, i.e. $(Q^TQ)^{1/2}$ if $Q$ is real).

Comment: Thank you. This also helps with the uniqueness issue.

Comment: Glad I could help. Basically, $U$ is uniquely determined if $Q$ is invertible (because then $M$ is invertible). If $M$ is not invertible, then there will always be infinitely many choices for $U$ as you will be free to determine it on a nonzero subspace.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for not trying harder before asking the question, but I have a solution, at least to finding one such $U.$

Let $Q = S\Sigma T$ be the singular value decomposition of $Q$ and set $U = (ST)^T.$ Then

\begin{align*}
QU &= S\Sigma T (ST)^T \\
&= S \Sigma T T^T S^T\\ 
&= S \Sigma S^T \\
\end{align*} which is symmetric.